# Telegram bot doesn't receive messages via webhooks

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I've tried to set up a webhook for python Telegram bot on a VPS server. It worked for an hour, but when I modified it, it stopped receiving messages. I rolled back to the simplest version of it — still no response.

Here's the full story:

At first it worked great! I've used echo bot example to try webhooks out.

Then I moved my main bot from polling to webhooks. I've changed echo bot message handler to what my main bot does and it also worked. Not perfectly, but it wrote logs with all received messages.

I terminated this bot with Ctrl + C on SSH terminal and later that day tried to launch it, but then it doesn't seem to respond. I've rolled back to the simplest echo bot example — nothing there.

I've made few screens trying to figure out if it's closed ports or whatever. But I didn't touch any of that part since middle of the day, when bot was working correctly.
Here are the links to the terminal screens:

1. [Is my bot listening to the right address?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhtlV.png)
2. [That's all bot does now — no updates on messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccQ0p.png)

Comment: It is only listening on port 443, are you accessing it on https?

Comment: What do you mean? I'm using this [example code](https://github.com/MasterGroosha/telegram-tutorial/commit/c1a86e14ed08c33d3791de7b05f6973a8acc7bfb).

Comment: What URL are you using for the webhook?

Comment: I'm not sure, it's addition of:
URL_BASE = "https://%s:%s" % (WEBHOOK_HOST, WEBHOOK_PORT)
URL_PATH = "/%s/" % config.token
URL = URL_BASE + URL_PATH

Comment: It makes something like: https://134.0.118.243:443/token/

Comment: Since you are using "https://" you don't need to add the port.

Comment: The most intresting part that it was working and just stopped receiving messages for no reason. I rolled back to the example code, still doesn't work.

Comment: if I delete "s" from "https" it raises error:

raise ApiException(msg, method_name, result)
telebot.apihelper.ApiException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 400 Bad Request. Response body:
[b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: bad webhook: HTTPS url must be provided for webhook"}']

Comment: Check your web server log. Is there anything in access_log?

Comment: It's very strange what is inside, I don't understand anything about Alipay and proxyjudge.us. Nothing about Telegram either. Here's the log: https://yadi.sk/d/gI_08cAS3LPhPo

Comment: Look what I've found. There's a webhook and pending updates.
https://api.telegram.org/bot367313352:AAEocbToR7HOAmsYFDev0pLYuwAmvNwyz5U/getWebhookInfo

Comment: I don't know anything about telegram. Maybe you could contact them?